# How to convert a text like "\320\272\320\276\320\274..." to std::wstring in C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I am working on a code that processes message from Ubuntu, some of the messages contains, for example:

*localhost sshd 1658 - -  Invalid user \320\272\320\276\320\274\320\274\321\320\275\320\270\320\267\320\274 from 172.28.60.28 port 50712 ]*

where "\320\272\320\276\320\274\320\274\321\320\275\320\270\320\267\320\274" is the user name that originally is in Russian. How to convert it to std::wstring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers after the backslashes are the UTF-8 byte sequence values of the Cyrillic letters, each byte represented as an octal number.

You could for example use a regex replace to replace each `\ooo` with its value so that you get a real UTF-8 string out:

[See it on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SsVWYmC7Ofg41qaD)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string const source = R"(Invalid user \320\272\320\276\320\274\320\274\321\320\275\320\270\320\267\320\274 from 172.28.60.28 port 50712)";
    boost::regex const re(R"(\\\d\d\d)");

    auto const replacer = [](boost::smatch const& match, auto it) {
        auto const byteVal = std::stoi(&match[0].str()[1], 0, 8);
        *it = static_cast<char>(byteVal);
        return ++it;
    };
    std::string const out = boost::regex_replace(source, re, replacer);

    std::cout << out << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you really need to, you can then convert this `std::string` to `std::wstring` using e.g. [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178510/481061)'s method.

Comment: converted the string to "Invalid user ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¼ÑÐ½Ð¸Ð·Ð¼ from 172.28.60.28 port 62291\n", but utf8Converter.from_bytes() still throws "bad conversion". strange... what can be wrong....?

Comment: The conversion itself works fine, but looks like sometimes I get not a valid UTF8 strings. So the both answers are very good! But you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `std::string` containing UTF-8 code-points and you wish to convert this to `std::wstring` you can do this in the following way, using the [`std::codecvt_utf8`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) facet and the [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) class template:

```
#include <locale>
std::wstring convert(const std::string& utf8String) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter{};
    return converter.from_bytes(utf8String);
}
```

The format of the resulting `std::wstring` will either be UCS2 (on Windows platforms) or UCS4 (most non-Windows platforms).

Note, that the `std::codecvt_utf8` facet is deprecated as of C++17, and instead consumers are encouraged to rely on specialized unicode/text-processing libraries. But this should suffice for now.

Comment: As far as I understand it, OP has actual literal backslashes and numbers in their string and needs to parse these numbers into unicode first, so this doesn't help much

Comment: Oh right, I misunderstood - I thought the OP was stating that their string contained the code-points corresponding to those characters! I will leave this here until we get further clarification.

Comment: It is not clear enough, what is utf8String? If I pass "\320\272\320\276" I get std::bad_conversion.

Comment: Looks like I should also use std::regex

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky see my answer on how to do it with a regex, however `std::regex` doesn't have a handy overload which accepts a replacer function. So I used Boost.

Comment: Still cannot figure out what it actually does, see http://rextester.com/live/OHBE38330. Why the output is empty?